# How to upload one sheet within an Excel workbook to SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, excel

I have multiple Excel workbooks. All of these workbooks have one tab with the same name and format (called "Summary_Table").

My question is: Is it possible to pull and upload this "Summary_table" sheet from multiple excel workbooks into 1 consolidated SharePoint List?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No Out of the box solution has designed so far in SharePoint to pull multiple sheet in one go. Either merge to one sheet or write custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to upload multiple excel workbooks into one SharePoint List. As a workaround, you should upload multiple excel workbooks to multiple different SharePoint lists.